# how to use PageEvent in tapestry4 to sendRedirect to another page

Tags: java, tapestry

```
public void pageValidate(PageEvent event) {
        //how to use pageEvent to sendRedirect to google.com ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an external site, use:

```
throw new RedirectException("http://google.com")
```

To redirect to a page withing the application use:

```
throw new PageRedirectException("page");
```